# Linq .GroupBy .Where .Select new Grouping item

Tags: c#, linq, grouping, projection

I'm trying to build a change log query that pulls logs since last revision.

I now need to consolidate the logs based on some rules.

Here's my Changelog Model:

```
public abstract class ChangeLogObject : TrackedObject {
    /// <summary>
    /// Type of transaction that occured
    /// </summary>
    public ChangeType ChangeType { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Original Id of the stateful object this changelog was created against
    /// </summary>
    public long EntityId { get; set; }

}
public enum ChangeType {
    Created,
    Updated,
    Deleted
}
```

So the steps I need to follow are:

1. Get where Id > last revision
2. Group By EntityId
3. Don't bring back any groups where the entity has ChangeType.Created and ChangeType.Deleted
4. Don't bring back ChangeType.Updated records if there's a ChangeType.Deleted but no ChangeType.Created (remove updated records from the group)
5. Only bring back the last ChangeType.Updated record if there are multiples
6. If the group contains ChangeType.Created and ChangeType.Updated then only bring back the last ChangeType.Updated but change it to ChangeType.Created

This is how far I've got but I don't know how to 'bring back part of a group':

```
        var newChanges = 
            // 1. Get where greater than last revision
            srcSet.Where(x => x.Id > lastRevision)

            // 2. Group by EntityId
            .GroupBy(x => x.EntityId)

            // 3. Don't bring back created and deleted (it's come and gone)
            .Where(x => !(x.Any(y => y.ChangeType == ChangeType.Created) &&
                        x.Any(y => y.ChangeType == ChangeType.Deleted)))

            // 4. Only bring back Deleted if no created (don't edit something you're about to delete)
            .Where(x => (!x.Any(y => y.ChangeType == ChangeType.Created) && 
                        x.Any(y => y.ChangeType == ChangeType.Deleted)))
                        //create new grouping, but only use the delete record????

            //convert back to individual change logs
            .Select(x => x.ToList()
            //maybe order by ID?
            .OrderBy(y => y.Id));
```

For 4. How do I turn x into a new group with only the records/values that are ChangeType.Deleted if the group itself doesn't contain a ChangeType.Created but may contain ChangeType.Updated?

Comment: it might be easier if you split this big query into smaller ones with intermediate result variables

Comment: How do you mean? Select out all the parts individually and Union them? or pull them into memory and then operate on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some assumptions I've made:

1. `srcSet` is a a set of `ChangeLogObject` items.
2. As per requirement 5 in your list, to enable the retrieval of the "last" item, you should be able to sort the list by some value. For this I've introduced a `ChangeDate` field, which is the date on which the change occurred.

In my sample, `TrackedObject` looks like the below:

```
public abstract class TrackedObject
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime ChangeDate { get; set; }
}
```

I've broken down each step of the query and numbered them according to the requirement:

```
var lastRevision = 2;
var srcSet = new List<ChangeLogObject>();

// 1. & 2.
var entityGroupsByEntityId = srcSet
    .Where(m => m.Id > lastRevision) // greater than last revision
    //.OrderByDescending(m => m.ChangeDate)
    .GroupBy(m => m.EntityId)
    .Select(group => new
    {
        EntityId = group.Key,
        ChangeCount = group.Count(),
        Changes = group.ToList().OrderByDescending(m => m.ChangeDate)
    });

//  3.
var entityGroupsWithNoDeleteAndCreate = entityGroupsByEntityId
    .Where(group => !(group.Changes.Any(m => m.ChangeType == ChangeType.Created) 
    && group.Changes.Any(m => m.ChangeType == ChangeType.Deleted))); // it doesn't contain both creates and deletes

// 4. 
var entityGroupsWithoutDeletedAndNoCreate = entityGroupsWithNoDeleteAndCreate
    .Where(group => !(group.Changes.Any(m => m.ChangeType == ChangeType.Deleted) 
    && (group.Changes.Count(m => m.ChangeType == ChangeType.Created) < 1))); // it doesn't contain a delete without a create

// 5. 
var entityGroupsWithUpdatedButNoCreated = entityGroupsWithoutDeletedAndNoCreate
    .Where(group => group.Changes.Any(m => m.ChangeType == ChangeType.Updated) 
    && !group.Changes.Any(m => m.ChangeType == ChangeType.Created)) // it updated but not created
    .Select(group => new ChangeLogObject
    {
        EntityId = group.EntityId,
        ChangeDate = group.Changes.First().ChangeDate,
        ChangeType = group.Changes.First().ChangeType // don't change the type
    });

// 6.
var entityGroupsWithCreatedAndUpdatedOnly = entityGroupsWithoutDeletedAndNoCreate
    .Where(group => group.Changes.Any(m => m.ChangeType == ChangeType.Created) 
    && group.Changes.Any(m => m.ChangeType == ChangeType.Updated)) // it contains both created and updated
    .Select(group => new ChangeLogObject
    {
        EntityId = group.EntityId,
        ChangeDate = group.Changes.First(m => m.ChangeType == ChangeType.Updated).ChangeDate, // bring back the first updated record
        ChangeType = ChangeType.Created // change the type to created
    });

// Join the 2 sets of Updated and Created changes
var finalResult = entityGroupsWithUpdatedButNoCreated.Union(entityGroupsWithCreatedAndUpdatedOnly).ToList();
```

Caveat:

1. The linq statements are not optimised for performance as these are not wrapped in IQueryable to ensure that these queries are evaluated on the database and not In-memory.

This should be enough to get you started on breaking down each part of your requirement into a query.

Comment: You have truly gone above and beyond mate, thank you so much. I'm pretty confident I can make this work (if it doesn't right off the bat) but I think I have a framework issue with EntityFrameworkCore so I'm going to ask another question about the picture I've uploaded in my edit :)

Comment: I got it working by putting a ToList() before the group by, not ideal but until Core is a little more fleshed out it won't make any difference in terms of efficiency. I'm also using Generics so I had to cast using `(DomainChangeLog)(object)group.Changes.First()` because `srcSet = db.Set<DomainChangeLog>(); where DomainChangeLog : ChangeLogObject`

Comment: Glad this could help, if this is using a relational data store behind the scenes, I would suggest creating this as a SQL view. :)